# My data list in controller is empty when change view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I don't understand why, but in Angular controller I have list, and if I success save file I want to go to another page and there show list of files which I save. I put name in list and everything is ok, but probably when I change html/root they deleted all list. I use same controller for two html page.

Controller:

```
  $scope.imenaFajlova = []; 
  $scope.continueFileUpload=function (){
     for (var i = 0;i<(file.files.length);i++) {
         $scope.nameFile.push(file.files[i].name);
     }

     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: uploadUrl,

         })
           .success(function(data, status) {  
               document.getElementById("fromFileUpload").reset();
               $location.path('/success');
           })
           .error(function(data, status) {
           });
 };
```

config:

```
uploadFile.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider,$routeParams) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'resources/html/home.html',
        controller : 'uploadFileController'
    })
    .when('/success', {
        templateUrl : 'resources/html/success.html',
        controller : 'uploadFileController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

How can I send date to another view or save data when chanfe root url?

Comment: Controllers are re-created every time you change views. Use services instead

Comment: Thanks for the advice ... definitely I need to use the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested you should use a factory or a service.

In case of a factory you first write a factory

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('namesFactory', namesFactory);

    function namesFactory() {

        var names = [];

        return {
            pushNames: pushNames,
            getNames: getNames
        };

        function pushNames(x) {
            names.push(x);
        }

        function getNames() {
            return names;
        }

    }
```

then you inject a factory dependency to your controller and use the methods from the factory inside your controller.

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('NamesController', NamesController);

    function NamesController($scope, namesFactory) {

        namesFactory.pushNames("Ante");
        console.log(namesFactory.getNames()); // prints ["Ante"] to the console

        $scope.names = namesFactory.getNames();

    }
```

For ng-repeat you would then use something like

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat='name in names'>{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a service that will handle this data move between pages, rather than using the same controller.

You can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) about services.

Comment: Yes, now names are in list ... but have another problem ... `factory('namesService', ['$window', function(win) {
    var names= [];
    return function(name) {
     names.push(name);
      if (names.length == 4) {
        win.alert(names[1]);
        names= [];
      }
    };
  }]);`  .... when I call `<ul data-ng-repeat='name in names'>` ... it's nothing happen ...? how to cal list from service in html code?

Comment: When you write a factory you need to write two functions inside one that sets the data and one that gets the data... You import the factory module into the original controller and set the data through that, and then in the new page controller you use the get function and put the data into a scope variable that you can call from the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Using Same controller doesn't mean, it is sharing the same instance of the controller. They either need to have a common parent, which is not reinitialized, or store data in a factory/service and read it from there.